# redirect http://uwww. http://www

Tags: url, redirect

I am with SEO programming and I have had a issue with one of the redirects. I need to redirect http://uwww.example.com to http://www.example.com and also example.com to hhh.example.com. Is thatpossible?
I tried

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

But it is showing errors.
 It would be great if somebody can help me out.